# JS: How to add a user input to a static array of an object instance within click event handler

Tags: javascript

My problem: I have a simple use input based app, where an events listener on click catches several user input parameter, creates a new object and then shall add the object to an static array as part of a new object. However it is impossible to store the new user object permanently. When I run the code it appears as if the array gets overwritten/newly created after each event handler which was triggered. Strange to me: when I console log the array within the event handler function and debug it, all seems to go correctly. Once the code execution finished and I console log the static object array it is reset to the initial status.

My question: How to create an object within a fired event handler function and write it permanently into another objects static array variable?

```
class DateList {
  dates = [];

  constructor() {}

  push(date) {
    this.dates.push(date);
  }
}

class Date {
  constructor(title, season, url, description) {
    this.title = title;
    this.season = season;
    this.url = url;
    this.description = description;
  }
}

class App {
  static dateList;

  static init() {
    this.dateList = new DateList();
    const date1 = new Date("Wandern", "Sommer", "www.wandern.de", "Schönen Wanderausflug machen!");
    this.dateList.push(date1);
  }

  static addDateToList(date) {
    this.dateList.push(date);
  }
}

const submitTitle = document.getElementById("title");
const submitSeason = document.getElementById("season");
const submitUrl = document.getElementById("url");
const submitDescription = document.getElementById("description");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", submitHandler);

function submitHandler() {
  App.addDateToList(createNewDate());
  console.log(App.dateList);
}

function createNewDate() {
  let date = new Date(
    submitTitle.value,
    submitSeason.value,
    submitUrl.value,
    submitDescription.value
  );
  return date;
}

App.init();
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: `new Date` is a built-in date object creator. You try to replace that with an pojo creator. I would start by renaming Date to something else, like userEvent. Also what do you mean by "permanent"? Surviving a reload?

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, thanks for your response. Why does renaming the object help? With permanent I mainly mean "stored into a global variable/object" on initial execution. I am aware that on a reload the data is reset. However in the case above the "static DateList" gets overwritten after the event fires.

Comment: Ah okay. I changed [<class Date>] to [<class DateItem>] but it has the same effect. Besides I think since I define a class "Date" within the code, it prioritizes my own class over the built-in class when creating an instance of it.

Comment: It is HIGHLY recommended to NOT try to replace built-in method names with your own. If you need any date handling, it will now fail

Comment: Also you have still neither 1. made a [mcve] nor 2. explained what you mean by permanently

Comment: Could it be you submit the page?
`function submitHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); /* stop submission */
  App.addDateToList(createNewDate());
  console.log(App.dateList);
}`